# CakePHP Error: The requested address '/admin/news/add' was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

**/app/Controller/NewsController.php**

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class NewsController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('Pages', 'News');


public function admin_index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'News' => array(
            'id' => 'News.created DESC',
            'content' => array('content'),
            'limit'=>50
        )
    );
    $news = $this->paginate('News');
    $this->set('news',$news);
}

public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') || !empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->loadModel('News');
        $n = $this->News->findById($this->request->data('News.id'));
        if (empty($n)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User not found', 'flash', array('class' => 'danger'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->request->data['News']['id'] = $n['News']['id'];
            $this->News->id = $n['News']['id'];
            $this->News->saveField('content',$n['News']['content']);
            $this->News->saveField('date',$n['News']['date']);
            $this->News->saveField('slug','enabled');
            $this->News->create();
            $this->News->save($this->request->data);
        }
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    exit(0);
}

}
```

**/app/View/News/admin_index.ctp**

```
<div class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid #B1B1B1;padding: 20px;border-radius: 6px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #D1D1D1;font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('News',array('url'=>array('action'=>'add'),'class'=>'form-inline'));?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('content',array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'News to update','required','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('date',array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'YYYY-MM-DD','required','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
```

**SQL Table**
Table Name: news
Structure:

1. AI - id
2. Varchar - content
3. Date - date
4. Varchar - slug

I'm trying to add News to my database but i'm getting error. Each news i'll add will be inserted into the DB in a new row.

**Error Logs**

```html
    2017-07-23 16:00:22 Error: [BadRequestException] The request has been black-holed
    Request URL: /admin/news/add
    Stack Trace:
    #0 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php(239): SecurityComponent->blackHole(Object(NewsController), 'auth')
    #1 [internal function]: SecurityComponent->startup(Object(NewsController))
    #2 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php(132): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #3 [internal function]: ObjectCollection->trigger(Object(CakeEvent))
    #4 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(247): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
    #5 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(675): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
    #6 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(182): Controller->startupProcess()
    #7 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(160): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(NewsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
    #8 /home/username/public_html/socialdealers.in/app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
    #9 {main}
```

**app/Config/routes.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
Router::connect('/apis/*', array('controller' => 'apis', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/api.php/*', array('controller' => 'apis', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/pages/api', array('controller' => 'apis', 'action' => 'apihelp'));

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
$prefix = 'admin';

//Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

Router::connect("/{$prefix}/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));

Router::connect("/{$prefix}/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
Thank you **Szymon** for solving most of my issues.

Edited NewsController.php

```
$data['News']['date'] = $this->request->data['News']['date']['year'].'-'.$this->request->data['News']['date']['month'].'-'.$this->request->data['News']['date']['day'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your routing is correct. You are trying to reach "admin" prefixed action "add", so this error means that there can be something wrong with routing.

Try to specify prefix in your route array. Instead of:

```
'url'=>array('action'=>'add')
```

try using:

```
'url'=>array('action'=>'add', 'prefix' => 'admin')
```

More info: [CakePHP 2 Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

Comment: I still have the same error even after adding the prefix and tried removing the prefix from the function. Any other solution ?

Comment: Could you please update your question with logs regarding this error, and your CakePHP routing configuration for this action?

Comment: Done as you requested.

Comment: I see that you are using SecurityComponent, and this component is blackholing your request for some reason. Is this error showing always when you try to access your action, or only when you are submitting your form? Maybe it is not recognizing field "slug", as you didn't used form helper to generate this field, so please use form helper for this field, and check if this solves your problem.

Comment: You were right. I made some changed to the code. I'm editing the 1st post. It not giving out errors now but the DB Query is not working. I removed the "slug" from admin_index.ctp and also changed the savefield for slug to "enabled". You were helpful till now i hope you can help me further.

Comment: If model is not saving data, check for validation errors: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Comment: I not good at it. I tried to learn what you said but i guess i'm not able to fix the issue. It would be great if you can help me though.